# com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ActiveManagementCoordinator.attemptManageC3P0Registry A C3P0Registry mbean is already registered

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am facing this problem, I am running multiple application on same server and database are differnt, I am facing following problem , Kindly help to resolve this problem

com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ActiveManagementCoordinator.attemptManageC3P0Registry A C3P0Registry mbean is already registered. This probably means that an application using c3p0 was undeployed, but not all PooledDataSources were closed prior to undeployment. This may lead to resource leaks over time. Please take care to close all PooledDataSources.